# Explicit cast to date in Xpath 2.0- unknown namespace prefix?

Tags: xslt-2.0

I have created an XSLT 2.0 stylesheet and want to explicitly cast a string to a date using `xs:date`.

Specifically looks like this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-dateTime( xs:date(concat (EDI_DC40/CREDAT,EDI_DC40/CREDAT, 'T', EDI_DC40/CREDAT,EDI_DC40/CRETIM), '[Y0001]-[M01]-[D01]T[h1]:[m01]:[s01]')"/>
```

Then a validation message is thrown indicating that the namespace prefix `xs:` is not defined.

Any idea what needs to be done or what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the XML Schema namespace in your stylesheet in order to use the functions in the XML Schema namespace. It isn't declared and available by default.

```
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
```